# iOS: posting image to webservice

Tags: ios, image, web-services, post, nsstring

I would like to post image to a webservice with the format below:

picture=%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%01%01%03%00%00%00%25%DBV%CA%00%00%00%04gAMA%00%00%B1%8F%0B%FCa%05%00%00%00%01sRGB%00%AE%CE%1C%E9%00%00%00+cHRM%00%00z%26%00%00%80%84%00%00%FA%00%00%00%80%E8%00%00u0%00%00%EA%60%00%00%3A%98%00%00%17p%9C%BAQ%3C%00%00%00%06PLTE%11%0B%0C%FF%FF%FFPU%C0J%00%00%00%01tRNS%94%B7%84%8F%3B%00%00%00%01bKGD%01%FF%02-%DE%00%00%00%09pHYs%00%00%00H%00%00%00H%00F%C9k%3E%00%00%00%0AIDAT%08%D7c%60%00%00%00%02%00%01%E2%21%BC3%00%00%00%25tEXtdate%3Acreate%002013-01-06T12%3A31%3A53%2B02%3A00%92R%3A%D3%00%00%00%25tEXtdate%3Amodify%002013-01-06T12%3A31%3A53%2B02%3A00%E3%0F%82o%00%00%00%19tEXtSoftware%00Adobe+ImageReadyq%C9e%3C%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82

My problem is how to convert an image to this format.

Thanks to any help.

Comment: I am unsure what that is but have you had a look at https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request this will allow you to attach data to the request. So you could convert your image to NSData using UIImagePNGRepresetation then once the rest of the request is filled in this should be sent on the request. I do this to upload images to a webservice so I know it is possible.

Comment: To Fogmeister:this is my problem, i don't have any idea about this format.
To Popeye: i tried this solution but webservice don't create image. Specification of webservice indicate that i should send image like this!!

Comment: @lightspeed that's not a good start. If you don't know the format then how you going to know what to encode it in. Maybe find out what this is encoded in then come back and update your question.

Comment: @Popeye: I asked here to know if there is someone how worked with image like this to help, i'm really blocked !!

Comment: @lightspeed if you try it the way I have send in my comment you could just than start encoding the `NSData` and print it to console and see which one it is.

Comment: Thx Popeye, i solved my pb:
imageStringASCII = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. If someone need it:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.photoImageView.image);
NSString *imageStringASCII = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

convert your image into Base64 i.e., encode with help of the following library of [Base64](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64/)

and upload image to server . In te server  decode and convert into image and store